# Avoiding to instantiate object in test files

Tags: scala, scalatest

I have a Redis PubSub object:

```
object RedisPubSubService {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("RedisEtatyLib")

  val config = ConfigFactory.load.getObject("redis").toConfig
  val hostname = config.getString("master")
  val port = config.getInt("port")
  val client = RedisClient(hostname, port)

  val address: InetSocketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(hostname, port)
  val channels = Seq("DASHBOARDS")
  val patterns = Seq("pattern.*")
  var callback: Boolean => Unit = { m => }

  val subscriber = system.actorOf(Props(classOf[SubscribeActor], address, channels, patterns, callback)
    .withDispatcher("rediscala.rediscala-client-worker-dispatcher")
  )

  def publish(channel: String, msg: String) =
     client.publish(channel, msg)
}

class SubscribeActor(address: InetSocketAddress,
                     channels: Seq[String] = Nil,
                     patterns: Seq[String] = Nil,
                     callback: Boolean => Unit)
  extends RedisSubscriberActor(address, channels, patterns, Option(""), callback) {

  def onMessage(message: Message): Unit = {
    // stuff
  }
}
```

The problem is that I don't need this object to be instantiated when I run tests in Jenkins. Due of that, my tests failed because are trying to connect to a redis server which I use on localhost (is setted in `application.conf`). I just want to ignore this object in my tests, because anyway, I don't use it.

How I instantiate the app in test file:

```
val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder().disable[StartUpService].build()
```

where `StartUpService` is a singleton class. But fo objects, I can not disable it in this way.

> [[37minfo[0m] p.a.i.l.c.CoordinatedShutdownSupport - Starting
> synchronous coordinated shutdown with ServerStoppedReason reason and
> 2147533000 milliseconds timeout [[37minfo[0m] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer -
> Terminating server binding for /0.0.0.0:9001 [[37minfo[0m]
> p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Running provided shutdown stop hooks CONNECTING
> COMMAND FAILED, cause = Some(java.net.ConnectException: Connection
> timed out)

thx

> Solution

Based on @Tim response, I found that the `module` class instantiate some object in the app

```
class Module extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[StartUpService]).asEagerSingleton
    bind(classOf[TraitRepository]).to(classOf[ClassRepository])
  }
}
```

Due of `StartUpService` class, where I instantiate a lot of services, all these are fired in all tests where I build the app object. The solution was to create a `TestModule` (without StartUp class) and use it in overriding the first.

```
object TestModule extends AbstractModule {
  override def configure() = {
    bind(classOf[TraitRepository]).to(classOf[ClassRepository])
  }
}
```

And now I can create the app object without firing all the services, as:

```
val app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
        .disable[Module]
        .overrides(TestModule)
        .build()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `object` is only initialised when a member of the `object` is accessed, so you must be using at least one value in `RedisPubSubService` in your tests.

The clean solution is to move all the values used in the tests into a separate class (`RedisPubSubConfig`?) and only have the real service code in `RedisPubSubService`. That way the service will only be created when it is used.

The tests can use a Mock service that is in a separate `object` (`RedisPubSubMock`?) that also uses `RedisPubSubConfig`. The code in this `object` will only be initialised during the tests.

Alternatively you can make the relevant `val`s `lazy` so they are only intialised when they are first used.

Comment: thx. I isolated the client configuration by the service how you said. For an unknown reason, `Guice` ignore the option `disable[StartUpService]`, and from there, the object `RedisService` is initialised (because a RedisService method is called). Using disable, I'm expected that `StartUpService` to be totaly ignored. This can be happened because I declare `StartUpService` as `EagerSingleton` inside configure method in `Module`? eg: `bind(classOf[StartUpService]).asEagerSingleton`